# How to keed type of variable when starting new Thread on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have this function:

```
import threading

def threaded(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return wrapper
```

And I use it to make my other functions run on a new Thread like that:

```
@threaded
def createUser(user: User):
    print("\nUser name:" + str(user.name))
   ...
```

The method `createUser` works perfectly when I call it without this notation, but when it's running on a new Thread I receive the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Does anyone know how can I avoid this error and keep the variable typed inside this Thread call? I also tried to run it as a normal Thread call like:

```
threading.Thread(target=createUser, args=[user]).start()
```

But it still not works!

Comment: How are you creating `user`? If you're getting the same error with the code at the bottom, `user` is just `None`. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Python and most other languages erase types before runtime. If you want types to be enforced you need to run a static type checker such as mypy over your codebase *before* you execute it.

Comment: To be clear though, the `None` isn't coming about because type hints are being lost. It's happening because a `None` is being passed somewhere.

Comment: +1 for @Carcigenicate's request.  We need to know how you create `user`.  I created a minimal working example that instantiates a `User` with a `name`, then passes the instance to `createUser`.  The `name` prints out as expected. Therefore your `user` argument is somehow `None`, and that may be enough to answer your question.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all your help. I will close this question because I'm starting to see that maybe my problem is another one. I will open another one with better description of my problem and a minimal working example. Again, thanks for helping!